# Jquery ajax gives error when moved to a .js file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

in a asp.net MVC3 application I have this jquery ajax function

```
function CheckValue() {
    var Returnvalue ="";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("CheckValue", "Home")',
        async: false,
        success: function (Value) {
            Returnvalue= Value;
        },
        complete: function (IsValid) {
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }

    })
    return Returnvalue;
}
```

What it does is call an action from the HomeController called CheckValue() that returns a value.

When I had it in my view page it worked correctly. But then, I moved it to a .js file `MyFunctions.js` and included the file in my view

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MyFunctions.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and the ajax does not work anymore.
I get an alert "Not Found"

any idea on the problem? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: you get an alert "Not Found" ? attach a screenshot of it with you quetsion

Comment: the alert comes from the error: handler error: `function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert(errorThrown);}` in the code above. Why should I include a screenshot? it is just a normal alert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that your code is now in `.js` file, yet it contains `C#` code, specifically `@Url.Action("CheckValue", "Home")`. `.js` files are not compiled or interpreted, hence the error you get. Also, the way your code was structured is incorrect. You need to return the value in the `success` handler due to the AJAX call being asynchronous.

The fix is to pass the url as a parameter of your function:

```
function CheckValue(url) {
    var Returnvalue ="";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        success: function (Value) {
            return Value;
        },
        complete: function (IsValid) {
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }    
    })
}
```

Then in your page you can pass the C# variable to the javascript function:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MyFunctions.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    CheckValue('@Url.Action("CheckValue", "Home")');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way of injecting MVC controller url's is through a server side rendered settings JS

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    Response.Expires = 120;
    Response.CacheControl = "public";
    Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
}

MyApp = {};
MyApp.settings = {
    checkValueUrl: "@Url.Action("CheckValue", "Home")"
};
```